# ASA's USB ports

Tags: cisco, usb, cisco-asa

I have three USB ports on my Cisco ASA 5505. All Cisco documentation that I've found says that they're for 'future use'.

Anyone know if this has been updated? Or if it will be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this hasn't changed.  The newer Cisco ACE's USB ports are for "future use" as well.

Comment: It's easy enough to upgrade via tftp but it'd be even easier to upgrade via a USB stick!! IOS has the ability to browse file systems, why not just add a mount function! It's a little ridiculous to just have a vestigial USB port for a reason that Cisco hasn't figured out yet.

Comment: I honestly think that they are there because they come on the motherboard (thinking of the ACEs here, haven't seen the back of an ASA) and it was cheaper to leave them there than to do a custom board without them.  Especially with the ACE which is just a 1U server (complete with video port) running IOS or something similar on it.